# Why is Request::current() null after upgrade from Kohana 3.0 to 3.1?

Tags: php, request, kohana

We upgraded our Kohana framework from 3.0 to 3.1 and so in the bootstrap.php file I had to change:

```
request = Request::instance($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

to

```
$request = Request::current();
```

but now $request is always null.

**What do I have to change so that `Request::current()` returns a request instead of null?**

Answer (score 3):

You need call `Request::factory()` to create initial Request object. `Request::current()` doesnt create new request, just returns current.

Also, you need to change your index.php and bootstrap.php files, because Request execution [was moved into index.php](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.1/master/index.php#L108).

**PS**. Maybe [this link](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/upgrading) will helps.